# Exploring 'typedef' to create a limited string data type?

Tags: c, typedef

I'm trying to create my own data type of string, could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong with typedef and initialization.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

typedef char string[10];


int main(){


    string myName;

    myName = "Tayyab";

    printf("This is %s", myName);



    getch();
}
```

Comment: I know we can declare string by including a header file of string.h

Comment: there is no type string in C. By including `string.h` you add the declarations of some functions that deal with null-terminating strings

Comment: This -1 is because I'm beginner???... is this place for Pros only?

Comment: Is this facebook or youtube where you want likes? Upvotes/Downvotes on SO are to differentiate good questions from bad questions. You shouldn't take it personally. If you really want to get into this, you could have easily done some testing to see what is wrong: it looks like there is a problem with your typedef: first thing to try: use the type (`char [10]`) instead of the typedef. You would have seen the same error: conclusion: your error not related to tyepdef. You could have proceed in the same manner to see that you can initialize but not assign to an array (continuing...)

Comment: ... but the real problem with your question is that you don't specify what is wrong with your code: the compiler error and at which line it appears. In this case it is a trivial problem and a decent C programmer can spot it and answer your, but it is a very bad habit of throwing a code and just saying: "it doesn't work" without even the minimum of specifying what it means it doesn't work: compiler error, run-time error, incorrect result.

Comment: Thanks I will better follow this next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was actually doing is not allowed in C language. Which is first I'm defining a character array of  `string[10]`then in the next statement I'm assigning a string value to it, it's only possible when I assign and initialize the character array at the same time.

So in other case, I have to assign every character one-by-one or I can use strcpy() to copy the string value into my character array in step.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot assign to an array but you can initialize it:

```
string myName = "Tayyab";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are `typedef`ing an array of `char`, you can't assign to it, however you can copy characters into it or assign to single elements, for instance

```
myName[0] = 'T';
myName[1] = 'a';
myName[2] = 'y';
myName[3] = 'y';
myName[4] = 'a';
myName[5] = 'b';
myName[6] = '\0' /* <- you should add a null terminator (c style strings) */;
```

or

```
strncpy(myName, "Tayyab", sizeof(myName));
```

but be careful the second case may omit the `null` termintaing `'\0'` if it was not present in the source string.

And of course, you can use initialialization syntax as **ouah** suggests.

Comment: The second case also omits the terminating null character '\0' if `strlen("Tayyab") >= sizeof(myName)`

Comment: In the second case, it is already omitting null terminator I think.  Should I have to write the second case this way "Tayyab\0" to avoid omitting null terminator?

Comment: No, it's already implied when you write `"Tayyab"`, i've seen that a lot, but it's not needed. Chux comment, is for the case wher le length of the source string exceeds the length of the destination buffer, in that case the null byte wont be added by `strncpy` so to be sure, you can do something like `myName[sizeof(myName) - 1] = '\0';` right after `strncpy`.

Comment: but I have read in a book strncpy automatically adds null terminator. Why we need to apply your condition then?

Comment: It does add the null terminator, but there is an exception, when the null byte is not present in the source string or it is after the specified number of bytes, then it will copy the specified number of bytes without checking weather there is a null terminator, that's for performance reasons obviously.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `typedef` and replace its usage with what the `typedef` is supposed to represent, your `main` function becomes:

```
int main(){

    char myName[10];

    myName = "Tayyab";

    printf("This is %s", myName);

    getch();
}
```

If you know why the line

```
    myName = "Tayyab";
```

is wrong in this version, you know the answer to your question.

Comment: I know it by the way, I'm just exploring.